# Checkbox default unchecked

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

For my Wordpress plugin option page I want to use checkboxes to set the options. I'm using this code to add it to the option page and it works well. Except that I want the checkboxes default set to unchecked. How do I do this?

```
public function id_number_callback()
{
printf(
'<input id="%1$s" name="cus_func_option[%1$s]" type="checkbox" %2$s" />',
'add_image_dimesions',
checked( isset( $this->options['add_image_dimesions'] ), true, false )
);
```

**Edit:** The full code I want to use is this

```
class MySettingsPage
{
/**
 * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks 
 */
private $options;

/**
 * Start up
 */
public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
}

/**
 * Add options page
 */
public function add_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be under "Settings"
    add_options_page(
        'Settings Admin', 
        'Custom functions', 
        'manage_options', 
        'cus-func-admin', 
        array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
    );
}

/**
 * Options page callback
 */
public function create_admin_page()
{
    // Set class property
    $this->options = get_option( 'cus_func_option' );
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
    <h2>Custom Functions</h2>           
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php
        // This prints out all hidden setting fields
        settings_fields( 'cus_func_group' );   
        do_settings_sections( 'cus-func-admin' );
        submit_button(); 
    ?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}

/**
 * Register and add settings
 */
public function page_init()
{        
    register_setting(
        'cus_func_group', // Option group
        'cus_func_option', // Option name
        array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
    );

    add_settings_section(
        'setting_section_id', // ID
        'Which Custom Functions do you want to use?', // Title
        array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
        'cus-func-admin' // Page
    );  

    add_settings_field(
        'add_image_dimesions', // ID
        'Add image dimesions to the Media Page', // Title 
        array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
        'cus-func-admin', // Page
        'setting_section_id' // Section           
    );      

    add_settings_field(
        'title', 
        'Title', 
        array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
        'cus-func-admin', 
        'setting_section_id'
    );      
}

/**
 * Sanitize each setting field as needed
 *
 * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
 */
public function sanitize( $input )
{
    $new_input = array();
    if( isset( $input['add_image_dimesions'] ) )
        $new_input['add_image_dimesions'] = absint( $input['add_image_dimesions'] );

    if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
        $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

    return $new_input;
}

/** 
 * Print the Section text
 */
public function print_section_info()
{
    print 'Pick your Custom Functions below:';
}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
public function id_number_callback()
{


    printf(
        '<input id="%1$s" name="cus_func_option[%1$s]" type="checkbox" %2$s" />',
'add_image_dimesions',
checked( isset( $this->options['add_image_dimesions'] ), true, false )
);

}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
public function title_callback()
{


printf(
        '<input id="%1$s" name="cus_func_option[%1$s]" type="checkbox" %2$s />',
'title',
checked( isset( $this->options['title'] ), true, false )
);  


}
}

if( is_admin() )
$my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```

Comment: The code works as expected. The first time the custom page is loaded, the checkboxes are `unchecked`. If we check/uncheck and save, it saves ok. I don't see what the problem is. (?)

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. I just installed it on a new website and the checkboxes were empty indeed. Maybe there was still some saved data from a previous trial. But at least it made me understand the whole thing better, although I'm stuck again. Please, look forward to my next question. Getting closer to my goal, and happy to learn more about WP plugins.

Comment: You'll find more plugin developers at [wordpress.se]. The tag [**`<plugin-development>`**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) has some pretty good material.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, brasofilo. I sometimes end up there via Google search, but maybe I should also see what's under plugin-development.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [WordPress Documentation for checked](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked)

What is the value of `isset( $this->options['add_image_dimesions'] )` in your code?

This is what is determining whether it's checked or not.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but when I want to check the checkbox and save it, the box is unchecked again.

Comment: What is the value of $this->options['add_image_dimensions'] ?

Comment: Nowhere in that code is your $options variable set, so this should presumably return `false` always.  You need to set / save the option value for this to function.

Comment: No sure if I understand. The code is based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798378/multiple-settings-wordpress-options-page-plugin and instead of the textfields I want to have checkboxes. Which kind of works, only the default needs to be changed to unchecked.

Comment: Do you want *default* to be unchecked, but if it is changed and saved, then for it to display checked?  If so, then you need to set the $option value properly in your class.  Right now, $this->option is never set / updated.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to set the $option properly so it will show the default unchecked box? I'm spending already 6 hours to get this working and I'm stuck. Thank you.

Comment: I have added $this->options = array(
   'add_image_dimesions' => '0', 
   'title'    => '0' 
   
  );

above $this->options = get_option( 'cus_func_option' ); and it seems to work. Hopefully is this what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkbox to **always** be unchecked when the page is loaded, then you can just remove the second printf token, `%2$2`, and the second argument to printf, `checked( isset( $this->options['add_image_dimesions'] ), true, false )`, which will give you this:

```
public function id_number_callback()
{
printf(
'<input id="%1$s" name="cus_func_option[%1$s]" type="checkbox" />',
'add_image_dimesions'
);
```

Comment: Same thing as with cale_b, when I tick the box and save it, the box returns to unchecked again (while the code I am using now leaves the tick after I save it, and removes the tick after I save the unchecked box.